# ExtJS Grid Message When No Records Found

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

I'm using ExtJS 4.0 grid and want to display a message (or HTML, or component)  inside the grid area when there are no records found.  I've been rummaging through their code for a while and can't seem to find any evidence that this exists natively in their library.  Is there a config or method I can use for this or will I have to roll my own?

Thx

Answer (score 8):

ExtJS 4 do provide you with the functionality of displaying a message inside the grid area when there is no records in your grid's store. You need to use the viewConfig for doing this. Here is an example:

```
viewConfig: {
    emptyText: 'There are no records to display'        
}
```

Now, if you are using a local store (or loading data directly to the grid using `data`) then you will need to set `deferEmptyText` to false. This is clearly explained in the documentation of [grid's view](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.grid.View.html). Refer to the config properties `emptyText` and `deferEmptyText`.

Answer (score 2):

ExtJS 4.1

```
emptyText: 'No Record to Display',
viewConfig: { 
    deferEmptyText: false
}
```

worked for me...
:)

Answer (score 1):

This configuration will solve your problem

viewConfig : {
       emptyText: 'No Record to Display',
       deferEmptyText: false
}

Answer (score 0):

Does not show. Searching for 'No Records...' in chrome inspect I do find the element, but it is not visible on the screen
{
            xtype: 'grid',
            viewConfig : { emptyText: 'No Records to Display', deferEmptyText: false },
            title: '',
            id: 'resultsTableGrid',
            store: me.store,
            columns:gridColumns
            }

Answer (score -2):

As 'Abdel Olakara' said, the following works when fetching from remote server on ExtJS Version: 4.0

```
viewConfig : {
        emptyText: "No Records....",                    
        deferEmptyText: false
}
```

Comment: Seriously? You took the time to post an answer that provides no original thoughts and merely copies another user's answer?